# Loading an website content in a dialog window

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am exploring [jQuery.get() ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype)  call to load a website content into my HTML page. The problem is that I am not too sure whether I am using the command correctly

For example:
I would like to load the following [website content from google](http://www.google.com/maps/place?source=uds&q=cafe&cid=10972320184180601304) to my HTML page.

I use the following jQuery script to do it :

`$.get("http://www.google.com/maps/place?source=uds&q=cafe&cid=10972320184180601304");`

Hoping that it will give me back the website content so that I can append it into my HTML page. I cant seem to get any response back from the `$.get(...)`.

Am I going to the right direction here or should I be looking for a different approach altogether ?

Cheers

Comment: I just found this from : "i think it is worth mentioning that some browsers don't accept loading a page from another source. ie, in firefox you can't use .load("http://www.abc.com"); in safari it does seem to work." (http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the browser security model prevents you from doing this. The best you'll be able to achieve is having the other page shown in an iframe.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: I found a good jQuery plugin called Fancy Box (http://fancybox.net/) to load website within iFrame. It is very to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

And your js:

```
$("#foo").load("http://someurl");
```

Comment: I tried the `$("#foo").load("http://someurl");`. It does not work. It works if I specify an internal html page within my directory